# Should simultaneous HTTP connections to a new HTTP 1.1 server create one connection or several connections?

Tags: http

#### Question

If 2 HTTP requests are made to the same server *at the same time* from fresh, e.g. `GET /image1.png HTTP/1.1` & `GET /image2.png HTTP/1.1` *with no previous connection to the server*. Then should 1 TCP connection be made or 2?

---

#### Info

[Persistent connections supported by default in HTTP 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). HTTP 1.0 uses the `Connection: Keep-Alive`.

It seems pretty clear from reading the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html) that if the above requests are made one after each other then the second request should reuse the connection.

[HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is sending multiple requests down the same connection without first waiting for a response.  I am not sure where this fit into the answer tho.

Comment: This sounds entirely dependant on the http library you use

Comment: @FrederickCheung: The question was if they _should_. The answer to this question is not dependent on a single implementation.

Answer (score 3):

*If 2 HTTP requests are made to the same server at the same time from fresh, e.g. GET /image1.png*

If the requests are made by the browser simultaneously (and there is no HTTP proxy server), then there will be two connections made to the server (unless [http pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is enabled). Per the wikipedia article on pipelining,

> Out of all the major browsers, only Opera based on Presto layout engine had a fully working implementation that was enabled by default. In all other browsers HTTP pipelining is disabled or not implemented.
>
> Internet Explorer 8 does not pipeline requests, due to concerns regarding buggy proxies and head-of-line blocking.
>
> Mozilla browsers (such as Mozilla Firefox, SeaMonkey and Camino) support pipelining, however it is disabled by default. Pipelining is disabled by default to avoid issues with misbehaving servers. When pipelining is enabled, Mozilla browsers use some heuristics, especially to turn pipelining off for older IIS servers.
>
> Konqueror 2.0 supports pipelining, but it's disabled by default.
>
> Google Chrome supports pipelining for HTTP in the stable release as a non-default option (starting with version 18). There is no support for pipelining HTTPS yet.[11] As of version 26, the flag to enable HTTP pipelining in Chrome has been disabled.

So, probably two connections.